# Add string to sitemap.xml file inside <urlset> tag in PHP

Tags: php

I tried to add a string into the sitemap.xml file inside `<urlset>` tag, but it stores differently.

```
<?php
$date_mod = date('Y-m-d');
$sitemap = "<url>
  <loc>http://www.website.com/article.php?page=3</loc>
  <lastmod>$date_mod</lastmod>
  <priority>0</priority>
</url>";


 $xml = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
$xml->addChild($sitemap);

file_put_contents("sitemap.xml", $xml->asXML());

 ?>
```

The output is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.website.com/article.php?page=3</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-01-12</lastmod>
  <priority>0</priority>
</url>
<//www.website.com/article.php?page=3</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-01-12</lastmod>
  <priority>0</priority>
</url>/></urlset>
```

Please help me.

Comment: PHP thinks the / is a node name .. escape using http:\/\/www.website

Comment: if i put VV in // place,the same error is diplaying bro

Comment: and y url and loc tags are not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the raw xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset>
</urlset>
```

And you updated xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset>
    <url>
    <loc>http://www.website.com/article.php?page=3</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-01-12</lastmod>
    <priority>0</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Then you could refer to the following code:

```
<?php
$date_mod = date('Y-m-d');
$sitemap = "<url>
<loc>http://www.website.com/article.php?page=3</loc>
<lastmod>$date_mod</lastmod>
<priority>0</priority>
</url>";

$sitemap_node =simplexml_load_string($sitemap);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");
sxml_append($xml,$sitemap_node);
$xml->asXML('sitemap.xml');

function sxml_append(SimpleXMLElement $to, SimpleXMLElement $from) {
    $toDom = dom_import_simplexml($to);
    $fromDom = dom_import_simplexml($from);
    $toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->importNode($fromDom, true));
}

?>
```

Your previous code failed to do that is because `addChild` method can only deal with text (and stil has some drawbacks), not another xml object.